# Transactional annotation for subclass fails to inject bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I was trying to use EntityManager to persist some entries to database.

the following code works fine,

```
@Transactional(value = "txnABC", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class ABC {
       @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sampleUnitName")
       EntityManager entityManager;
       
      public void save(Object input){
            entityManager.persist(input)
      }

}
```

However, when I extend an abstract class `CommonActions` as below

```
public abstract CommonActions{
      public abstract void save(Object input);

      public void sayHi(){
      }
}

@Transactional(value = "txnABC", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class ABC extends  CommonActions{
     @override
     public void save(Object input){
            entityManager.persist(input)
      }
}
```

Then the following error is raised,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'abc' is expected to be of type 'ABC' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48'
```

Is it possible to use the annotation `@Transactional` in sub class ?